# Copying data from file into a specific location of another file with dd truncates the output file

Tags: linux, filesystems, dd

I have a loopback file that contains a single filesystem, let's call it `fs.image`. I have another, much larger loopback file, that contains multiple partitions and multiple filesystems, let's call it `disk.image`.

`fs.image` is exactly the same size as one of the partitions in `disk.image`. I would like to copy the data from it into the `disk.image` file into the correct location.

I have a script that computes the proper offset, and attempts to do this with `dd`. I assumed this would work because it works with a block device, but this isn't the case. `disk.image` is truncated at the position immediately following the data that was just written into it.

**Is there any way to keep `dd` from truncating the file?**

`fs.image` is compressed as `fs.image.bz2`, and the command I'm executing is like this:

```
bzcat fs.image.bz2 | dd of=disk.image bs=4M seek=$OFFSET
```

where `$OFFSET` is my computed offset.

I've thought about other ways of accomplishing this, but this seems the simplest (if it worked). Once option would be to copy data up to the point of insertion to another file, append the filesystem, and finally append the remainder of the original file. However, this would be slow because I'd be copying a lot of data I don't really need to. I'm open to other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU's `dd` (at least version 8.23) has the following *conversion flag*

> **notrunc**
>       do not truncate the output file

which does exactly what you want; here is a small example:

```
$ cat foo
foobar
$ echo -n XX | dd of=foo bs=1c seek=1 conv=notrunc
2+0 records in
2+0 records out
2 bytes (2 B) copied, 0.000283698 s, 7.0 kB/s
$ cat foo
fXXbar
```